# What demographics are available from Google Play?

Tags: android, google-play

I'm in my fourth year at university and I was considering making an Android application as part of my dissertation.

I was wondering, what sort of demographics are available for Apps that are downloaded? e.g. Age, Sex, Location, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Google Play Developer Console gives you some statistics about your application installs/usage, but it is limited to mostly technical data:

- Android Version
- Device
- Country
- Language
- App Version
- Carrier

So for your purpose it looks like only country and possibly language are relevant. If you need more information you'll have to ask the user (or trick them into telling you ;) ).

Answer (score 0):

In the developer console you have the following statistics:

- Downloads over time
- Android version
- Device
- Country (of download)
- Language (of the device)
- Active installs by app version
- Carrier